# comando update-database não funciona em multiplos contextos

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho dois `context` em meu projeto.

Segui como base instruções desse [Artigo](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html)
aonde o mesmo mostra como ter 2 `context` no mesmo projeto.

Cada `context` é  para bancos separado, logo são 2 `ConnectionString`

Entretanto ao usar o comando `update-database` nada acontece, a syntax usada é a mesma mencionada no artigo:

```
Update-Database -configuration NameSpace.Configuration -Force -Verbose
```

No arquivo de `Configuration` em ambos `migrations` contém essa configuração:

```
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"AppMigrations";
```

Eu acrescentei mais uma propriedade em minha `class`, entretanto ele não gera a coluna no banco de dados.

Estou usando `Code First`

**[Edit]**
O código de cada contexto é:

Contexto 1

```
  public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario, Role, int, UsuarioLogin, UsuarioRole, UsuarioClaim>
  {
    public MyDbContext()
      : base("MyConnection")
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new AppDbInitializer());
    }
    #region DbSets
    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

      modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
      .Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
    }
    public static MyDbContext Create()
    {
      return new MyDbContext();
    }
  }
```

Meu Contexto 2:

```
 public class GlobalDbContext : DbContext
  {
    public GlobalDbContext()
      : base("GlobalConnection")
    {
      Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<GlobalDbContext>(null);
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

      modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
      .Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<CBO> CBOs { get; set; }
  }
```

**Motivo de utilizar 2 contexto:**

Um banco de dados(representado pelo contexto 1) é para a cada cliente
O contexto global, são tabelas que serão utilizado em todos os clientes, logo, um banco de dados global com informações simples para não se repetir em todos os bancos

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @Renan eu fiz diferente, não usei outro db...pois seria mais um db para dar manutenção, como os dados não iriam se compartilhar com outras aplicações, eu coloquei tudo no mesmo db